# concat column values with previous row if there is null in another column in same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

df:

```
col1      col2       col3
 1        cat          4
nan       dog         nan 
 3        tiger         3
 2        lion          9
 nan      frog         nan
 nan     elephant      nan
```

I want to create a data frame from this data frame that id there is nan values in col1, col2 values will be added to the previous row value.

for example the desired output data frame will be:

```
col1     col2             col3
 1      catdog             4
 3       tiger             3
 2     lionfrogelephant    9
```

How to do this using pandas ?

Comment: How working my solution?

Comment: yes, thanks , working

Comment: Thank you for accepting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use forward filling missing values and aggregate `join`:

```
cols = ['col1','col3']
df[cols] = df[cols].ffill()
df = df.groupby(cols)['col2'].apply(''.join).reset_index()
print (df)
   col1  col3              col2
0   1.0   4.0            catdog
1   2.0   9.0  lionfrogelephant
2   3.0   3.0             tiger
```

Or if necessary forward filling missing values in all columns:

```
df = df.ffill().groupby(['col1','col3'])['col2'].apply(''.join).reset_index()
print (df)
   col1  col3              col2
0   1.0   4.0            catdog
1   2.0   9.0  lionfrogelephant
2   3.0   3.0             tiger
```

Comment: Mine is same problem, but data is not always missing in col1 or col3, sometime in col2 also. And when data is missing in col2, data is present in either col1 or col3 or in both. How to deal in this scenario. How to successfully attach present row data to previous row data?